# web config and machine config

Tags: asp.net

what is the differnce b/w  webconfig and machine config

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Web.config is specific to an application.

Machine.config applies across all applications on your server.

So, if i have 3 apps on the same server that share connection strings; machine.config is the way to go.

If i have application specific settings (say timeout interval) that vary across apps; put those in web.config

Answer (score 8):

Careful.  There is a hierarchy of config files:

`applicationHost.config` is the top-level IIS config file.

Next is `machine.config`, which is the top-level, server-specific config file.

Next is a server-level `web.config` file.

Then there is an application-specific `web.config`.

Next, there is an optional *application.config* file.

Finally, there are optional directory-specific `web.config` files.

The higher-level files often contain directives that limit what you can configure in the lower level files.  The highest-level `web.config`, for example, is where server trust levels are configured.

Answer (score 3):

They are two parts of the same system.  Microsoft put some magic in .NET so that machine.config and web.config are merged at runtime.  Machine.config provides defaults that web.config can override if you so choose.

Machine.config provides a way to hold configuration that is machine specific.  So say you have two environments Production and UAT which need to point to different databases.  You can put the connectionStrings for Production and UAT in machine.config on the Production and UAT boxes respectively, and all ASP.NET applications on those machines will have access to the appropriate connectionString.

You can read more about .NET configuration files [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xtk877y%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest reading up on [ASP.NET Configuration Inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685.aspx). There's other configuration layers besides `machine.config` and `web.config`, and it helps to know all of the different pieces that may be affecting your application.

Answer (score 1):

`machine.config` is a global configuration file containing default settings at machine level which could be overridden in `web.config` which is specific to a given application.